# Convert a short video from byte[] to String and retrieve and reconvert those bytes to Video

Tags: java, mp4

My Requirement:

1. Get all bytes from a video file.
2. put into a string.
3. Re-construct the video from that string

For 1: [working correctly]

```
private static byte[] readBytesFromFile(String filePath) {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    byte[] bytesArray = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];

        //read file into bytes[]
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        fileInputStream.read(bytesArray);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fileInputStream != null) {
            try {
                fileInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return bytesArray;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    byte[] bFile= readBytesFromFile("an mp4 video file in my system");
}
```

[Source](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-file-into-an-array-of-bytes/)

For 2. & 3:

```
FileOutPutStream out = new FileOutPutStream ("to Re-convert mp4 video path");
```

If I write,

```
out.write(bFile);
out.close();
```

--> **It WORKS**

But that is not all what I need.

I need something kind of :

```
byte[] bytes = bFile;
String s = new String(bytes, Charset.defaultCharset());
bFile = s.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
```

and then :

```
    out.write(bFile);
    out.close();
```

--> It does not work.

How to implement this?

Comment: by definition a video can not be stored in a `String` in java not without extensive encoding and decoding because characters are not bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot expect something like this to work

```
new String(bytes, Charset.defaultCharset());
```

because you cannot expect an arbitrary sequence of bytes to represent a valid encoding of a string.

You should either choose a charset encoding in which any sequence of bytes represents a valid encoding or, better, convert to something like Base64

Comment: `byte[] bFile= readBytesFromFile("an mp4 video file in my system"); 
bFile = Base.decodeBase64(bFile); 
String s = new String(bFile,"UTF-8");` 

Getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at line 2

Comment: you should be _encoding_ to base64, not _decoding_.

Comment: Thanks , it is working. I dont know what wrong I have asked that it got so many negatives

Comment: I guess you got negatives because in your question (and the comment here) you showed some basic conceptual confusions (what a string is, what   it means to decode/encode something) and a lack of interest to understand, only to "make it work".

Answer (score -2):

I wrote this application. I think it's system independent (working in my environment - windows 10, jdk 9, default UTF-8. I hope it'll help you somehow:

```
public class SOFlow {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    byte[] allBytes = new byte[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < allBytes.length; i++) {
        allBytes[i] = (byte) i;

    }

    System.out.println("allBytes  " + Arrays.toString(allBytes));

    String strAllBytes = convertBytesArrayToString(allBytes);
    System.out.println("converted " + Arrays.toString(convertStringToBytesArray(strAllBytes)));
    System.out.println("String " + strAllBytes);
    System.out.println("String len " + strAllBytes.length());


}

public static String convertBytesArrayToString(byte[] bytesArray) {
    CharBuffer charBuff = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytesArray).asCharBuffer();
    return charBuff.toString();
}

public static byte[] convertStringToBytesArray(String str) {

    //IMHO, char in String always take TWO bytes (16 bits), while byte size is 8 bits
    //so, we have to 'extract' first 8 bites to byte and second 8 bites to byte

    byte[] converted = new byte[str.length() << 1]; //just half of str.lenght
    char strChar;
    int position;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        strChar = str.charAt(i);
        position = i << 1;
        converted[position] = (byte) ((strChar & 0xFF00) >> 8); //mask and shift
        converted[position + 1] = (byte) (strChar & 0x00FF); //mask
    }
    return converted;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you explain your code instead of just dumping it here?

Comment: @Robert I just added two comments in my code. I think that isn't necessary to explain masking and/or shifting bits. That would be the basic NOT, AND, OR, XOR expressions...

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Why it doesn't work? I had EXACT copy of all possible bytes CONVERTED to String and RE-CONVERTED to bytes? And, if I may add, it is not nice to down vote ANY answer before you try it.